# How to kill process on Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server

I am working remotely on a Windows Server via Remote Desktop Connection and some process has hung the server.  I looked up how to bring up the Task Manager remote (equivalent of locally doing CTRL+ALT+DEL) and I found CTRL+ALT+END and it doesn't seem to work.

I tried logging off and logging back on and the system is still up (tried earlier seeing the properties of My Comptuer, FYI).

Does anyone know how I can escape this 'hindrance' and star fresh?!?

Comment: You could open virtual keyboard, select the full keyboard from left upper icon, then click on CTRL+ALT+DEL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start the task manager with e.g right-clicking in the bottom right or just start it manually with taskmgr in "execute"

Comment: If the graceful "End Task" button in the Task Manager does not work (if app froze) alternatively you can right-click on the column headers of processes list, tick "PID" to see the process ID. Then open PowerShell and type `kill YOUR_PID_NUMBER` replacing "YOUR_PID_NUMBER" with the PID of the process you now see in Task Manager.